# Highlight a button based on location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to highlight a navigational button (in a menu) based on the page being viewed. Here is what I have so far:

```
var loca = String(document.location.href);

// Get document location and specific page.
if (loca) {
    if(loca.search(RegExp("((/[\w]*)\.php)")) != -1) {
        activate(loca.match(RegExp("((/[\w]*)\.php)").split("/").join("")));
    } else {
        activate("home");
    }
}

// Activate a button
function activate(bName) {
    $(".button[name=" + bName + "]").css({
        "border-left": "1px solid white",
        "border-right": "1px solid white"
    });
}
```

What I want to happen is this:

1. Get URL of page
2. Get the specific file name of page, and if not found, then we are on the homepage.
3. Using jQuery, I try to find the name of the button, and if the name matches the filename, then highlight it.

Thing is, this only highlights the "Home" button. What am I doing wrong? Also, if you have any suggestions on how I can better accomplish this, please let me know!

Comment: I also suggest making a CSS class and then adding/removing the class, rather than hard coding the values.

Comment: @Nick: I agree with you, and I had it that way before, but I was still having the same issue. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get the filename like this, instead:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var filename = pathname[pathname.length-1].split(".")[0];

alert(filename);
```

Comment: I like this way the most; a lot simpler and cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is incorrect.

```
var loc_match = window.location.href.match(/(\w+)\.php/);
activate(loc_match ? loc_match[1] : "home");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution but I would assume the regex is flawed.  Did you try to store the result in a variable and console.log it?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually implemented something like this. Here's my code:

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname.toLowerCase().split('/').reverse()[0].split('#')[0].split('?')[0];

if (!currentPage || currentPage == '')
{
    currentPage = 'default.aspx';
}

$('#nav li').removeClass('current').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).find('a').first().attr('href');
    if (href && href.toLowerCase().indexOf(currentPage) >= 0)
    {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }   
});
```

This takes into account any query strings or searches may be in the URL. Using `reverse()` may not be the most efficient way of doing it, but it certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your regexp as new RegExp object, you have to use double backslash escaping symbols (instead one backslash, when you just assign literal like `var a = /\w/i;` );
So, your code should work after some reg exp correction:

```
var loca = document.location.href;
var pattern = new RegExp("[\\w]*(?=\\.php)","i");
// Get document location and specific page.
    if(pattern.test(loca)) {
        activate(pattern.exec(loca));
    } else {
        activate("home");
    }
// Activate a button
function activate(bName) {
    $(".button[name=" + bName + "]").addClass('active')
}
```

And as already said, it's easier to assign class to your active element.

Comment: This works perfectly, I really appreciate the tip as well. :)