# JavaScript/jQuery count URL segments

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm looking for a good way to easily count URL segments using JavaScript/jQuery?

For example:

```
www.myurl.com/segment1/segment2/segment3
```

should return `3`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321468/how-to-get-the-parameter-from-a-url

Comment: @racecarjonathan the answer you posted isn't related. I'm trying to count the url segments not get the last segment. I googled and didn't find a straightforward solution.

Comment: I see. My apologies. <3 lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = "www.myurl.com/segment1/segment2/segment3";
var segment = url.split("/").length - 1 - (url.indexOf("http://")==-1?0:2);
console.log(segment);
```

If number of "/" are segments for you

Comment: I think this will return a number for the backslashes in `http://` as well. That's not good :(

Comment: View the updated answer. Mark it as correct answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 6):

```
var count = (location.pathname.split('/').length - 1) - (location.pathname[location.pathname.length - 1] == '/' ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: this returns `11` for 3 segments. Wouldn't just `location.pathname.length - 1` have been sufficient?

Comment: Thanks I forgot the split, have edited my post now. I think the last part is necessary because the URL may end in a slash which I think will count as an extra array element.