# Get data from URL address

Tags: javascript, url

I have a website like below:

```
localhost:3000/D129/1
```

D129 is a document name which changes and 1 is section within a document. 
Those two values change depends on what user selects.
How do I just extract D129 part from the URL using javascript?

Comment: Duplicates: [how to get the parameter from a url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321468/how-to-get-the-parameter-from-a-url) and [Last segment of URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758103/last-segment-of-url) and others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.pathname.match(/\/([a-zA-Z\d]*)/)[1]
```

^ that should get you the 1st string after the slash

```js
var path = "localhost:3000/D129/1";

alert(path.match(/\/([a-zA-Z\d]*)/)[1])
```

Comment: It seems like .pathname is only returning "/". Is this a correct way of accessing the URL?

Comment: @Kahsn what is the current path of your page? if you are on the root page then there is no path. Maybe you meant to get `window.location.hash` instead?

Comment: It is root of my app. And yes hash is returning #/d129/1. Do I just split this? or should I do the regex match?

Comment: @Kahsn use regex (i _think_ it is faster than split)

Comment: Any recommendation to make your regex work btw? I try users and I only get "i" as a result.

Comment: What is the sting you are trying to match @Kahsn ?

Comment: Oops. I had a wrong URL for you sry. What I actually have is `http://localhost:3001/#/D-129/1`. My bad. I try to match D-129

Comment: So just add `- ` to the regex `/\/([a-zA-Z\d\-]*)/`

Comment: Thanks for much help!

Comment: No problem :-) Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` and `[1]`:

```js
a = "localhost:3000/D129/1";
a = a.split("/");
alert(a[1]);
```

This works if your URLs always have the same format. Better to use RegEx. Wanted to answer in simple code. And if you have it with `http://` or something, then:

```js
a = "http://localhost:3000/D129/1";
a = a.split("/");
alert(a[3]);
```

> *ps: For the `RegEx` version, see [Tuvia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6220751/tuvia)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36702350/462627).*